# Identify duplicates rows based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

@SQL Experts,

I am trying to fetch duplicate records from SQL table where 1st Column and 2nd Column values are same but 3rd column values should be different.

Below is my table

```
ID    NAME     DEPT    
--------------------
1     VRK      CSE
1     VRK      ECE
2     AME      MEC
3     BMS      CVL
```

From the above table , i am trying to fetch first 2 rows, below is the Query, suggest me why isn't give correct results.

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.DEPT 
FROM TBL A
INNER JOIN TBL B ON A.ID = B.ID
                 AND A.NAME = B.NAME
                 AND A.DEPT <> B.DEPT
```

Somehow I am not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data does not make it completely clear what you want here.  Assuming you want to target groups of records having duplicate first/second columns with all third column values being unique, then we may try:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, DEPT
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, NAME, DEPT,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME) cnt,
        MIN(DEPT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME) min_dept,
        MAX(DEPT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, NAME) max_dept
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE cnt > 1 AND min_dept = max_dept;
```

Comment: Why would you need `COUNT(DISTINCT DEPT)`?

Comment: Hi Tim, does this work with SQL 2005? I am getting Syntax error near DISTINCT Keyword.

Comment: @user10164345 I had a mistake.  It isn't possible to use `COUNT` over with `DISTINCT`.  Try my updated version.

Comment: Thanks Tim , this is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

```
select *
from
(
    select *,
           COUNT(*) over (partition by id, [name]) cnt1,
           COUNT(*) over (partition by id, [name], dept) cnt2
    from dbo.T
) x
where x.cnt1 > 1 and x.cnt2 < x.cnt1;
```

Comment: Hi JOhny,
I want to filter those records where ID and NAME has same values and DEPT is different.

Comment: Thanks Johny , appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

For find duplicate column

```
select x.id, x.name, count(*) 
from  
    (select distinct a.id, a.name, a.dept 
     from tab a) x
group by x.id, x.name 
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: THank you Baskaran for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original rows, I would just go for `exists`:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where exists (select 1
              from tbl t
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.dept <> t.dept
             );
```

If you just want the `id`/`name` pairs:

```
select t.id, t.name
from tbl t
group by t.id, t.name
having min(t.dept) <> max(t.dept);
```